# How to read images from a folder with image name and path?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

- I need read all images from a folder and, inside folder I have another folder that will also I need to read and storing
- when I click a button open a dialog box for selecting a folder that time I need folder path and sub-folder also.

This code give fakepath how to solve?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showFileName() {
   var fil = document.getElementById("myFile");
   alert(fil.value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmMain" name="frmMain">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile"/>
    <a href="#" onclick="showFileName()">Show Name</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you confusing client side code with server side code?   You do not have any access to the folder structure on a client machine

Comment: then, how is it possible to read all files, selected a folder by client ? any idea...

Comment: It is under the user control, the user will pick and save files locally.  Its a security measure.

Comment: If the array is not very big and the array only applies to this user, you can save it to local storage.

Comment: what i need i tell to you, when user select a folder from his system that time i required get all files and folder how can do this ?